# Styling position of props in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styling

How to style 'Text' to blue circle having following code:

```
type WizardCircleProps = {
  wizardCircleContent: React.ReactNode;
};

const circleStyle = {
  background: '${props => props.theme.palette.active}',
  borderRadius: '50px',
  width: '32px',
  height: '32px',
  margin: '18px',
};

export class WizardCircle extends Component<WizardCircleProps> {

  render() {
    const { wizardCircleContent } = this.props;

  return (
    <div style={circleStyle}>
      **{wizardCircleContent}**
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Gave me:

[image]

My goal is to have:

[image]

I just want to center the 'Text' or similar text to the center of circle.

Comment: so basically you want any text inside blue circle are center ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a `css` problem.

Pay attention to `line-height` and `text-align`.

```css
#round {
  background: #00f;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: white;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
};
```

```html
<div id="round">1</div>
```

Comment: My issue is not to add CSS but to build such kind of component, my issue is how to apply/connect circle's CSS with Text's CSS.

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk You can do that by using `styled-component` https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props